# Advice on choosing the best data warehousing tools for ERP system on Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g, data-warehouse, erp, ifs-erp

I have been tasked with researching and implementing data warehousing for our ERP system (it's IFS if anyone happen to have prior experience). There is 137GB of data over more than 5000 tables.

Does anyone have any experience of data warehousing a large ERP system and can you recommend any tools or provide any advice on the matter. It's not something i've ever dealt with before.

Comment: IFS has it's own BI package now using the microsoft stack, Sql Server, SSIS, SSAS. You can buy cubes now for the different erp modules it has. You can then report off the cubes using your typical stuff, SSRS, Excel, Power BI. There are still some modules that don't have a cube though, in which case you could still make it yourself using the same SQL Server technology stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a huge topic.  We went with SQL-Server and Analysis Services for our warehouse (for Oracle eBiz ERP) - great tools and platform IMHO.

You really need to figure out how you're going to use the DW and based on that figure out what gives you the features and tools that you need.  The ERP has little relevence because ultimately you're going to be transforming the data from the ERP into whatever you need in the DW and that's where the real work comes in.